# updateQueryData in RTK doesn't update Redux State

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I would like to use `updateQueryData` to update some data in my Redux State.

```
export const useUpdateBankFeesByInvoiceId = ({ orderId, data, invoiceNumber}: ParamsBankFeesOrderSummary) => {
  
  return calcApi.util.updateQueryData('getBankFeesByOrderId', orderId, (draft) => {

    const newBankFees = draft?.map(invoice => invoice.invoice_num === invoiceNumber ? {
      ...invoice,
      banking_commissions: invoice.banking_commissions.map((bankingCommission: BankFees) =>
          bankingCommission.id === data.id ? data: bankingCommission
      ),
    } : invoice)

    return newBankFees;
  }

  );
}
```

When I dispatch that function:

```
const patchBankFees = dispatch(useUpdateBankFeesByInvoiceId(dataToSend));
```

But when I open Redux State I see the only difference in queries, there is no updates in the state app.

[image]

I also want the specific Redux State node get updated like in this screenshot:

[image]

I even added `patchQueryData` but result is the same:

```
export const usePatchBankFeesByInvoiceId = ({ orderId, func}) => {
  return calcApi.util.patchQueryData(
    'getBankFeesByOrderId',
    orderId,
    func.patches,
  );
}

dispatch(usePatchBankFeesByInvoiceId({ orderId, func: patchBankFees}))
```

What's wrong is there? When I used `upsertQueryData` instead of `updateQueryData` I've got the desired result. But the code was weird.

Comment: From that screenshot, it seems like it does what it should - what do you mean by "updates in the state app"?

Comment: I mean to update not only queries but also a related node in Redux State.

I want to have something like:

calcApi -> queries -> getBankFeesByOrderId({}) - it works.


But calcParams -> order -> bankFees ->
banking_commissions - doesn't work

Comment: And there's no good reason why it would. RTK Query has no idea that you have derived state from RTK Query results that you are storing somewhere else in your state - after all, that's logic you have written on top.
Generally, we recommend not to copy RTKQ state into manually managed Redux state if you can avoid it, and instead derive state within selectors if possible.

Comment: So, what should I do? I want to update the specific node in Redux State, let's say order.bankFees[1].bankCommission[2]. And I don't want to send data to backend immediately because I would like to update several bankCommissions (let's say order.bankFees[3].bankCommission[1], order.bankFees[4].bankCommission[0] also) and when to sent that information to backend in 1 request. How should I write my code?

Comment: Use selectors to combine the data from your slice and the data of your query, without ever moving data of the query into your slice.
If you feel that's not possible, you'll have to manually update data in both places. There's not magical synchronization mechanism here - again, this is additional logic you added on top. RTKQ doesn't know about it.